# Javascript strings - getting the char at a certain point

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

I have a variable:

```
var text = "hello";
```

I want to get the 0 positioned character, so:

```
var firstChar = text[0];
```

Simple. In firefox and chrome this works. In IE however i always get back 'undefined'

Any ideas why this might be happening in IE?

Comment: From now, learn that everything that works in `good` browsers doesn't work in `IE`. I think MS people wanted to code an extra dimension aside the current web development context.

Comment: Addenda: works fine in IE8 (as I write this), and in IE7 instead of throwing an error returns something that is parsedInt'ed as NaN instead of exploding. Tracking this problem sure took much longer than it should...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Strings aren't accessible like arrays in IE (prior to IE9). Instead you can use [`charAt`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_charAt.asp), which is available cross-browser:

```
var text = "hello";
var firstChar = text.charAt(0);
// firstChar will be 'h'
```

Comment: +1 for *charAt()*.  FWIW, IE8 in standards mode and IE9 support array-style referencing of characters in strings just like Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.substr()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp).

```
var firstChar = text.substr(0,1);
```

Comment: I'd use this as it's the most cross-browser compatible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why that doesn't work, but you could try using [substr()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp)