# Check if first letter of word is a capital letter

Tags: javascript, capitalize

Is it possible in JavaScript to find out if the first letter of a word is a capital letter?

Comment: Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027224/how-can-i-test-if-a-letter-in-a-string-is-uppercase-or-lowercase-using-javascrip

Comment: EDIT: Yes. Try `/^[A-Z]/.test(phrase)` ([here](http://jsfiddle.net/uAwQL/1/))

Comment: @DavidRodrigues potential pit trap there, `[A-Z]` doesn't match accented or non-ASCII capital letters, see new answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/39292247/568458

Answer (score 116):

**update**

Updating with what i think is the most valid approach nowadays.

You can use a [Unicode property escapes Regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes) if the [support](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_regexp_property_escapes) suits you. In this case you can use the [General category property](https://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#General_Category_Property) for Uppercase Letter `Lu`.

```
function isUppercase(word){
  return /^\p{Lu}/u.test( word );
}
```

---

older answers

```
var word = "Someword";
console.log( word[0] === word[0].toUpperCase() );
```

or

```
var word = "Someword";
console.log( /[A-Z]/.test( word[0]) );
```

or

```
var word = "Someword";
console.log( /^[A-Z]/.test( word) );
```

See [`toUpperCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) and [`test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

Comment: @Johnston : Look like you are misinterpreting the results from jsperf. The last option (/^[A-Z]/.test( word) ) seems to be the fastest. Check the test. The higher the value the better.

Comment: @Pratham It depends on the computer that is running it. But here is a screenshot of what my results look like. http://imgur.com/nv4nBE7. It says that the uppercase version does 13m ops/sec while the other does 5m ops/sec. It also says on mine that the regex is 60% slower. Am I reading it wrong?

Comment: @Johnston : Result from Firefox browser : http://imgur.com/1quk2fe . Looks like browser affects the performance

Comment: These are fine if you know you're only getting a string containing A-Z English characters, but the regex will misidentify accented / on-ASCII capital letters (e.g.  it'll return false for the names 'Łukasz' and Åland) and the `toUpperCase()` will treat non-letters like capital letters (e.g. it'll return true for '1940s' or '17th'). I've [added a (just as simple) alternative that meets these cases too](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39292247/568458).

Answer (score 38):

The other answers on this page are fine for strings that are known to only contain non-accented A-Z letters. If you can't guarantee this (e.g. user input), they may give unexpected results: false positives for uncapitalisable initials like "1940s" or "中文", or false negatives for accented or non-Roman capital initials like "Łukasz" or "Александра".

This variant returns true if the initial is *any* capital letter, and *only* if it's a capital letter:

```
function initialIsCapital( word ){
  return word[0] !== word[0].toLowerCase();
}
```

Use `.charAt(0)` instead of `[0]` [if you need IE8 support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668693/javascript-strings-getting-the-char-at-a-certain-point). Which [is faster varies between browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943726/string-charatx-or-stringx).

This avoids two potential pitfalls with the other answers:

- Regexes using `[A-Z]` will fail to match accented and other similar non-A-Z capitalised letters such as in  **Åland** (Scandinavian islands) and **Łukasz** (common Polish name), including capital letters in non-latin scripts such as Cyrillic or Greek (e.g. **Александра**).
- The approach using `word[0] === word[0].toUpperCase()`, will return true on words that start with non-letters, such as **1940s**, **17th**, **123reg** (company name), abbreviations like **2mrw**, or some words in some African languages, such as **!xūún** or **ǂǐ-sì**. It'll also treat any input from an alphabet that doesn't have capital letters as being capital letters (e.g. **中文**).

Since this arbitrary-input-safe approach is just as simple and no less readable than the alternatives, it's probably better to use this even if you don't anticipate such exceptions.

Here's a quick test:

```js
function a(word){
  return word[0] !== word[0].toLowerCase();
}
function b(word){
  return word[0] === word[0].toUpperCase();
}
function c(word){
  return /^[A-Z]/.test( word );
}
function test(word, answer){
  console.log( 'Should be '+answer+':',  a(word), b(word), c(word), '-------', word );
}

test( 'Łukasz', true ); // regex test fails, returns false
test( 'Александра', true ); // regex test fails, returns false
test( '1940s', false ); // .toUpperCase() test fails, returns true
test( '中文', false ); // .toUpperCase() test fails, returns true

test( 'ß', false ); // All pass on German "sharp S" that has no uppercase
test( 'Z̢̜̘͇̹̭a͎͚͔͕̩̬̭͈͞l̩̱̼̤̣g̲̪̱̼̘̜͟ợ̮̱͎̗̕ͅͅ', true ); // All pass. Phew, Zalgo not awakened
```

Answer (score 13):

For **English** letters only:

```
'A' => 65
'Z' => 90
```

Meaning, every number between [65, 90] is a capital letter:

```
function startsWithCapitalLetter(word) {
  return word.charCodeAt(0) >= 65 && word.charCodeAt(0) <= 90;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes.

```
var str = "Hello";
if(str[0].toUpperCase() == str[0])
{
   window.alert('First character is upper case.');  
}
```

Comment: Recommended since this seems to work, with a small amount of testing in Chrome, for Unicode characters like "È" (E with a grave) and "ζ" (non-capital zeta).

Answer (score 5):

You can do it in several ways:

```
var myWord = "Hello";

// with string functions
if (myWord.charAt(0) === myWord.charAt(0).toUpperCase()) { /* is upper */ }

// or for newer browsers that support array-style access to string characters
if (myWord[0] === myWord[0].toUpperCase()) { /* is upper */ }

// with regex - may not be appropriate for non-English uppercase
if (/^[A-Z]/.test(myWord) { /* is upper */ }
```

Note that the array-style access to characters like `myWord[0]` is an ECMAScript 5 feature and not supported in older browsers, so (for now) I'd probably recommend the [.charAt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) method.

If you need to do this test a lot you could make a little function:

```
function firstLetterIsUpper(str) {
   var f = str.charAt(0);   // or str[0] if not supporting older browsers
   return f.toUpperCase() === f;
}

if (firstLetterIsUpper(myWord)) { /* do something */ }
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the `match` method of the string object prototype:

```js
const word = 'Someword';
console.log(word.match(new RegExp(/^[A-Z]/)) !== null);
```

Comment: This might answer the question, but please also provide a short explanation, what your code does and why it solves the initial problem.

Comment: this is a regular experession matcher. read up yourself on language docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Comment: Regular-expressions ("RegEx") btw are not specific to JS, it is a topic of its own for which there are enough tutorials out there.

Answer (score 0):

```
var string1 = "this is a string";
var string2 = "This is a string";

if(string1[0] == string1[0].toUpperCase())
    alert('is upper case');
else
    alert('is not upper case');


if(string2[0] == string2[0].toUpperCase())
    alert('is upper case');
else
    alert('is not upper case');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Typescript**

```
//userEntry input as string
//return boolean
oneUppercaseRequired(userEntry: string): boolean {
   const letters = /[A-Z]/;

   if (letters.test(userEntry[0]))
     return true;

   return false;
}
```

**for-loop for other languages** Change the syntax to your language!

```
//userEntry param as string
//return boolean
oneUppercaseRequired(userEntry: string): boolean {
   const letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

   for (let i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
     if (userEntry[0] == letters[i])
       return true;
   }

   return false;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't hard-code logic for specific languages; if language is relevant, it's likely a user setting with multiple possibilities, and `toLowerCase` etc already covers every unicode character that is uppercase. No need to re-invent the wheel, creating brittle logic that only works for one language. Also, style tip: you never need `if (condition) { return true } return false`, `test` and `===` return booleans already, you can simply do `return someRegex.test(someString)`; and if you needed to loop through a string, you could do `return someString.includes(subString)`.

Comment: Misleading answer: The TypeScript code also works same for JavaScript (just remove the type annotations and you re fine, it is the same built in String functions). The for-loop approach is viable, but ineffctive (not to be used when reg-ex matchers available). This answer doesn't add anything to this already given one here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45307750/589493