# find whether first letter of a string is capital or not

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check if first letter of word is a capital letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334606/check-if-first-letter-of-word-is-a-capital-letter)

I want to write a function in which I pass string as argument. Then I want to find out whether the first letter of this string is capital or not. If it is capital then return true otherwise return false. How can I achieve this in javascript? Any simple demo, I will later modify according to my need.

Comment: Are you asking to check if the first *character* is a letter and is capital, or if merely the first letter of the string is capital? Those are two different things. Given your question, the following string should return true `"...123Abc"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use String.charCodeAt(). This function returns a a unicode value of the character. Uppercase letters have a different value than lowercase ones.

Check the docs:
http://dochub.io/#javascript/string.charcodeat

```
function isFirstLetterCapital(string) {
  return string.charCodeAt(0) === string.toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0);
}
```

**Edit:**

charAt is actually faster - http://jsperf.com/string-operations-order. 
Thanks Cerbrus for pointing this out.

```
function isFirstLetterCapital(string) {
  return string.charAt(0) === string.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
}
```

Comment: Use `string.charAt(0).toUpperCase();`, [that's lighter](http://jsperf.com/string-operations-order). Also, why `charCodeAt` instead of `charAt`?

Comment: but you can't uppercase a unicode value ;)

Comment: great stuff. charCodeAt was just the first thing that came to my mind.

Answer (score 4):

```
var myString = "Whatever you want to test"
console.log(myString[0] == myString[0].toUpperCase());
//Returns true

myString = "whatever you want to test"
console.log(myString[0] == myString[0].toUpperCase());
//Returns false
```

`myString[0]` doesn't work in (Somewhere around) IE7/IE8 and lower, use `myString.charAt(0)` if you need the script to be compatible with those browsers.

Comment: The "array syntax" for strings don't works on IE7 and less. Am i right ?

Comment: Might be, I'll modify accordingly. Edit: Yup, that's right.

Comment: IE 8 and lower have that issue.

Comment: @IHateLazy: All pages I find on it mention IE7 and lower.

Comment: According to [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ecczf11c%28v=vs.94%29.aspx): *"You can access an individual character of a string as a read-only array-indexed property. This feature was introduced in Internet Explorer 9 standards mode..."*

Comment: @IHateLazy: Hm, Editing... Damn you, Microsoft.

Comment: wait, I just fired up VirtualBox, and it seems to work in IE8. Strange that the docs would suggest otherewise.

Comment: @IHateLazy: There, this should cover it.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(yourString.match(/^[A-Z]/)) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function isFirstLetterUpperCase(string) {
   var firstLetter = string.charAt(0);
   return firstLetter == firstLetter.toUpperCase();
}
```