# How to make a textbox not type the first letter as a capital

Tags: javascript, html, textbox, web

Hi I have made a website with JavaScript and html were you type something into a textbox and it responds to you but when on an iOS device it is always making the first letter a capital and not recognizing the word. this has become very difficult. I have looked everywhere to find what I need and have come here as a last resort. I need some code to make the capital button not come up or make the text I write into the box be recognized if it has capitals or not. if you need any code to help please tell me and ill update it immediately with the code you need. I hope I can fix this problem.

Comment: Look at this post:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334606/check-if-first-letter-of-word-is-a-capital-letter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334606/check-if-first-letter-of-word-is-a-capital-letter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I would do:

```
<input id="myText" type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()">

function myFunction(){
    document.getElementById("myText").value = document.getElementById("myText").value.toLowerCase();
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jnj9yw86/)

Answer (score 1):

Before your treatment, you can add a Javascript Function toLowerCase http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolowercase.asp to convert your string in lower case, event if the string has one or all capitals letters.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle that using `autocapitalize` attribute.

Try this: `<input type="text" name="input" autocapitalize="off"/>`

Answer (score 0):

> val = val.substr(0, 1).toLowerCase() + val.substr(1);

or:

> val = val.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + val.substr(1);

Answer (score 0):

```html
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" OnTextChanged="textChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

and add this to .cs file:

```
protected void textChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.ToLower();
    }
```