# check if first letter of word is uppercased, solution evaluating false

Tags: javascript

before[0] is definitely uppercased, so I’m confused why it’s evaluating to false

```
function myReplace(str, before, after) {
    console.log(before[0] === before[0].toUpperCase();
}

myReplace("A quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog", "Jumped", "leaped");
```

Comment: Just copy @marvel308's answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if first letter of word is a capital letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334606/check-if-first-letter-of-word-is-a-capital-letter)

Answer (score 1):

you were referring to the function toUpperCase. you need to call it in order to get the value

```js
function myReplace(str, before, after) {
    console.log(before[0] === before[0].toUpperCase());
}

myReplace("A quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog", "Jumped", "leaped");
```

Answer (score 0):

This time you forgot to close the `console.log`, it should be:

```
  function myReplace(str, before, after) {
    console.log(before[0] === before[0].toUpperCase());
}

myReplace("A quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog", "Jumped", "leaped");
```

Answer (score 0):

Hell, you should add parentheses :

```
function myReplace(str, before, after) {
    console.log(before[0] === before[0].toUpperCase());
}

myReplace("A quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog", "Jumped", "leaped");
```