# Valid output in IE9 but undefined output in IE7/IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I wrote a simple 'replaceAll' function that extends String.prototype.

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function (removalChar, insertionChar) {
    var output = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if(this[i] == removalChar) {
            output += insertionChar;
        }
        else {
            output += this[i];
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Test code:

```
var test = "Hello-1-2-3";
alert(test.replaceAll("-"," "));
```

My test code alerts `Hello 1 2 3` in all browsers including IE9.

But in IE7 and 8, the output I get is something like this: `undefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefined...`

---

**jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cd4Z2/**
(try this in IE7/IE8)

---

How could I possibly rewrite the function to ensure it works on IE7/8 without breaking its behaviour on other browsers?

Comment: Thanks for all the super-quick responses! I've decided to 'accept' Saturnix's answer for being the most detailed, but Teemu's and wiz kid's answers are pretty cool too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access string chars with `this[i]` in IE7/8. Use `.charAt(i)` instead, as explained here:

[Javascript strings - getting the char at a certain point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668693/javascript-strings-getting-the-char-at-a-certain-point)

---

Updated fiddle (tested in IE8): http://jsfiddle.net/cd4Z2/2/

I've just replaced `this[i]` with `this.charAt(i)`.

---

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943726/string-charatx-or-stringx) question, some good reasons are stated on why you'd prefer to use `charAt` as opposed to `string[index]`. The latter is not part of ECMAScript 3.

Answer (score 2):

IE<9 don't treat a string like an array, i.e. they lack ability to refer individual letter with index. You can use a temporary array (`var temp = this.split('');`) instead of `this[i]`

Answer (score 2):

## Try this out:-

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function (removalChar, insertionChar) {
    var output = "";
    var res = this.split('');
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if(res[i] == removalChar) {
            output += insertionChar;
        }
        else {
            output += res[i];
        }
    }
    return output;
}


var test = "Hello-1-2-3";
//alert(test.replace("-"," "));
alert(test.replaceAll("-"," "));
```